# Apple Macintosh Model for Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4

I'm deadly interested in Cocoa. I want to begin to study Objective-C and to use Xcode. Please tell me what the minimal (let's say, the cheap one) Mac Model you'd like to recommend me. I am meaning for Xcode 4.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Mac you can buy at this moment will be fine. Your cheapest option would probably be the Mac mini if you have a decent screen already. Other good options can be the MacBook 13" (I use this is my main development machine) and iMac of you don't need to be mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Any new Mac. Or any used Intel-based Mac under 3 years old.